# How to get info from json object, not attributes?

Tags: json, ember.js

I have something like that:

```
"data":
 {
  "type": "type1",
  "id": "0",
  "name": "12345",
  "attributes": {
      "surname": "6789"
  }
 }
```

And my question is - how to get name in model? Because for surname I have:

```
surname: DS.attr('string')
```

and it works. But what if I want to get name which is not an attribute? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resembles a [json:api](http://jsonapi.org/) document. That spec says that all information about (attributes of) a model belong under the `attributes` key. So, the solution is for the server to move the `name` field under `attributes`, to comply with the spec.

Comment: I concur. alternatively if the server cant be changed, one could use a custom serializer.